# Dynamically Assign Concrete Class That Extends Abstract Class With Generic

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

I have the following class definitions

```
public class AbstractIem<T> where T : SomeObject 
{ 
    public abstract T Item { get; }
}

public class ConcreteItem1 : AbstractItem<ClassExtendingSomeObject>
{
    public override ClassExtendingSomeObject Item { get; }
}

public class ConcreteItem2 : AbstractItem<AnotherClassExtendingSomeObject> 
{
    public override ClassExtendingSomeObject Item { get; }
}
```

Where I run into the problem is when I want to dynamically assign an object of `AbstractItem<SomeObject>`,

```
AbstractItem<SomeObject> myItem;

switch (someIntValue) 
{
    case 1:
        myItem = new ConcreteItem1();
        break;
    case 2:
        myItem = new ConcreteItem2();
        break;
}
```

I get the following error when try to set `myItem`:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'ConcreteItem1' to 'AbstractItem'

I would've thought that this should work since each `ConcreteItem` class extends `AbstractItem<SomeObject>` where `SomeObject` is a concrete type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called variance and in C# it's only possible on interfaces. So, to make it work you'd have to change `AbstractItem<T>` into an interface and mark `T` as covariant.

```
public interface IItem<out T> where T : SomeObject
{
    T Item { get; }
}

public class ConcreteItem1 : IItem<ClassExtendingSomeObject>
{
    public ClassExtendingSomeObject Item { get; }
}

public class ConcreteItem2 : IItem<AnotherClassExtendingSomeObject>
{
    public AnotherClassExtendingSomeObject Item { get; }
}
```

Notice added `out` keyword in front of `T` in declaration of `IItem`.

With that setup following code works as expected:

```
IItem<SomeObject> myItem;

switch (someIntValue)
{
    case 1:
        myItem = new ConcreteItem1();
        break;
    case 2:
        myItem = new ConcreteItem2();
        break;
}
```

See [*Covariance and Contravariance in Generics*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance) at learn.microsoft.com for more information on covariance and contravariance in .NET.

Comment: Very interesting. I never heard of variance before. Is there a specific reason it can only be done on interfaces?